# #ifndef DIRECTORY HEADERFILE not found

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

How can I use directory in preprecessor command ifndef

**EXAMPLE**

```
#ifndef DIR/HEADERFILE_H 
#include "dir/headerfile.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Use a character the preprocessor allows? `#ifndef DIR_HEADERFILE_H`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The preprocessor understands text - not directory structures? Once a file has been `#included`d it doesn't then have the filename/directory #defined.

Comment: IT IS VERY INTERESTING, WHY I AM GETTING -2? SOME COMMENTS FIRST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specicif question, you cannot use a directory in a preprocessor command like `#ifndef`.

The include guards in the header file often take the form

```
#ifndef DIRECTORY_HEADERFILE_INCLUDED
#define DIRECTORY_HEADERFILE_INCLUDED

//.... contents

#endif
```

To include the header, then simple use

```
#include "dir/headerfile.h"
```

A long while ago some people suugested a double include guard, or redundant include guard, wherein you checked before the `#include` line to speed things up, as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805541/about-include-header-file-with-guards). The [c2 wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?RedundantIncludeGuards) has some further information esp.

> "Good compilers make this idiom unnecessary. "

In either case the tendacny is to use `_` instead of `/`, to form a valid macro.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names), only  alphanumeric characters and underscores (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`) are allowed for macro and constants names. You can define your own constant replacing `/` with `_`:

```
#ifndef DIR_HEADERFILE_H
```